# webpack 5.73.0 compiled successfully infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

i am trying to run a react webpack application however when i run the react app via npm run dev however the webpack build goes into an infinite loop. when i run npm run dev this is the output:

```
> frontend@1.0.0 dev
> webpack --mode development --watch

asset main.js 1.34 MiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related 
asset
runtime modules 1.04 KiB 5 modules     
cacheable modules 1.28 MiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.28 
MiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 85.7 KiB 2 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 992 KiB 2 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 17.3 KiB 2 modules
    + 3 modules
  modules by path ./src/ 1.82 KiB      
    ./src/index.js 35 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/components/App.js 438 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/components/HomePage.js 860 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/components/RoomJoinPage.js 281 bytes [built] [code generated]       
    ./src/components/CreateRoomPage.js 
249 bytes [built] [code generated]     
webpack 5.73.0 compiled successfully in 1216 ms
```

it then gets stuck after saying it compiled successfully. i'm not sure if  i am following this tutorial if it helps - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEmjBEDyVSY&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j&index=4 im using react 18 and "webpack": "^5.73.0" and "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1". i'm thinking i might have to downgrade to the tutorial versions but would rather not if possible.

here is my webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

any help much appreciated and happy to provide more info. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what `--watch` is designed to do. Webpack will enter an infinite loop watching your files and recompiling them as soon as they change. Remove `--watch` if it's not what you want to do.